# Auditing execution of stored procedures in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, audit

My boss and I have been trying to see what sort of auditing plan we could try for our stored procedures. Currently there're two external applications taking information from our database through stored procedures and we're interested in auditing when they're being executed, and what values are passed as parameters. So far what I've done is simply create a table for the stored procedures one of the apps is using, and as they use the same input parameters, have one column per parameter. Obviously this isn't the best choice, but we wanted to get quick info to see if they were running batch processes and when they were running them. I've tried SQL Server Audit, but it doesn't catch the parameters unless you're executing a SP in a query.

Comment: Do you have access to modify the code of the stored procedures?  Can you just modify them to log their parameters to a table in addition to their usual function?

Comment: @ScottChapman This is what I've done so far. But I have next to 50 SP and we're thinking of doing some data mining out of the audit info to optimize the database, so I need to somehow store the input values of those 50 SP, which complicates the design of tables. This is what I'll do if I can't find a better way.

Comment: If performance optimization is the goal and logging is just a means, what do you think about using the Database Engine Tuning Advisor?  It uses information captured in a profiler trace to determine what statistics and indexes help performance of the profiled load the most.  There are also Dynamic Management Views you can use to determine which queries are using the most resources or taking the most time.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Profiler will do this for you; its included for free. Setup a trace and let it run.

You can also apply quite a bit of filtering to the trace, so you don't need to track everything; you can also direct the output to a file, or sql table for later analysis. This is probably your best bet for a time limited audit.

Comment: I was thinking more of a permanent solution, plus we have very limited HW and SQL Server Profiler is very resource hungry.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've used the SQL Server Profiler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) in the past to audit SQL execution.  It's not something you would run all the time, but you can get a snapshot of what's running and how it's being executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I need to run it constantly, or at least to trigger it to log the execution when it happens, because I'm not sure when the stored procedures are executed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using them, but you might look at event notifications and see if they will work for you.

From BOL

> Event notifications can be used to do the following:
>
> Log and review changes or activity occurring on the database.